# Running thinkfan on Debian

Tags: debian, thinkpad

I am trying to use thinkfan on my x220 running debian jessie. While the installation went through, the systemd service fails to start. Any ideas?

```
Nov 20 13:43:38 thinkpad-x220 thinkfan[1762]: /proc/acpi/ibm/thermal: No such file or directory
Nov 20 13:43:38 thinkpad-x220 thinkfan[1762]: Error parsing temperatures:
Nov 20 13:43:38 thinkpad-x220 thinkfan[1762]: readconfig: Error getting temperature.
Nov 20 13:43:38 thinkpad-x220 thinkfan[1762]: Refusing to run without usable config file!
Nov 20 13:43:38 thinkpad-x220 systemd[1]: thinkfan.service: control process exited, code=exited status=4
Nov 20 13:43:38 thinkpad-x220 systemd[1]: Failed to start simple and lightweight fan control program.
```

I have `tp_smapi` and `thinkpad_acpi` modules loaded.

Comment: You don't have the thinkpad_acpi kernel module loaded.  Add the module to `/etc/modules`.

Comment: what makes you say that? I see that its already loaded when `lsmod | grep thinkpad`

Comment: Because the error message indicates that /proc/acpi/ibm/thermal is missing and that should be provided by that module.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit late but I leave the answer here just in case someone else has the same issue.

The problem is that /proc/acpi/ibm/thermal does not exist.
In order to read properly the temperatures you need to find your sensors location:

```
find /sys/devices -type f -name "temp*_input"
```

In my case, I added the two following lines to /etc/thinkfan.conf:

```
tp_fan /proc/acpi/ibm/fan

hwmon /sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0/hwmon/hwmon3/temp1_input
hwmon /sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0/hwmon/hwmon3/temp2_input
hwmon /sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0/hwmon/hwmon3/temp3_input
hwmon /sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0/hwmon/hwmon3/temp4_input
hwmon /sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0/hwmon/hwmon3/temp5_input
```

lm-sensors is recommended to be installed.